# Regex for multiline output - sed / awk / grep

Tags: regex, svn, awk, sed, grep

SVN log returns the below information but I am trying to get the revision number based on the comments.

Since the returned value is in multiline, is there a way to use regex to look for '1712' (in last line) and then return the corresponding revision number r1055457 (from first line) only for those matches?

```
r1055457 | test | 2017-10-26 12:02:33 -0700  (26 Oct 2010) | 3 lines
Changed paths:
M /search/config/legal.json
M /search/server/server.js
[1712]- test commmends
```

I tried couple of commands but its just returning everything that has either of the regex.

```
svn -v log search --limit 1 | awk '/^r[0-9]/,/1712/' 

svn -v log search --limit 1| sed -e '/^r[0-9]*/,/1712/!d'
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ ... | awk '/^r[0-9]+/{rev=$1} rev && /^\[1712\]/{print rev; rev=""}'

r1055457
```

Answer (score 0):

With sed

```
$ ... | sed -n '/^r[0-9][0-9]*/N;:A /\nr[0-9][0-9]*/D;/1712/!{s/\n.*//;N;bA};s/|.*\n.*//p'
```

Comment: @RavinderSinght13 The command doesn't work with the correction